# Passing username to a HttpGet request

Tags: java, http, http-headers, http-get

I need to access an API which works like this:

```
curl https://api.com/ratings/v1/ -u [your token here]:
```

The token is the username that should be passed to the `HttpGet` request. I am trying to do the same in the following way using java:

```
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("usrname", "passwrd"));
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("proxy.com", 8080, "http");
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setProxy(proxy).setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();

HttpGet toesGet = new HttpGet("https://api.com/ratings/v1/");

    toesGet.setHeader("Accept", "Application/Json");
    toesGet.addHeader("Username", "[your token here]");

    try {
        HttpResponse toes = httpClient.execute(toesGet);
        System.out.println(toes.getStatusLine());
        System.out.println(toes.getEntity().toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am a behind  proxy, so I am creating a `HttpHost` with the proxy details, setting the proxy for the `HttpClient` object and passing the credentials for proxy authentication using `credentialsProvider` in the following lines of code:

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("proxy.com", 8080, "http");
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setProxy(proxy).setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();
```

I am passing the `username` to the `HttpGet` by adding the `header` like this:

```
toesGet.addHeader("Username", "[your token here]");
```

when I run the code, I get this response: **`HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED`**

This indicates that I am not passing the `username` to the `HttpGet` request in the right way(Or does this mean something else?). So what's the right way of passing the username to the get request?

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you!

**Note:** The `usrname` and `passwrd` I set in the credentialsProvider are for the proxy authentication. They have nothing to do with the HttpGet request itself. the token I need to pass is different from the `usrname` provided in the credentials.

Comment: Calling `setDefaultCredentialsProvider` should be sufficient, assuming your user name and password are correct.  As far as I know, `Username` is not a valid header at all, so it’s probably doing nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The `username` and `password` I set in the `credentialsProvider` are for the proxy authentication. they have nothing to do with the HttpGet request itself. @VGR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven’t used Apache HttpComponents, but my understanding is that you have to set the credentials for specific hosts:

```
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("proxy.com", 8080, "http");
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(proxy),
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("usrname", "passwrd"));
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope("api.com", AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("apiuser", "apipassword"));
```

Note:  Do not actually type "apiuser" or "apipassword" in your code.  I am showing those only as placeholders.  Replace them with the correct user and password for accessing api.com.  (I am pointing this out because, based on the code in your question, I’m not sure if you understood that you were not supposed to use the literal string `"[your token here]"`.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to do what you've suggested. But I am still getting the same `unauthorized` response.

Comment: Initially I was giving the `Authscope` in a wrong way. corrected it now and it is working! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess, your server uses Basic Authentication, then you need to add the "Authorization" header instead of "Username":

```
String user = "[your token here]";
String pwd = ""; // blank
toesGet.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString((user + ":" + pwd).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));
```

or if your token contains user and pwd, then try it like that:

```
String token = "[your token here]";
toesGet.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(token.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried to use the above lines in my code and I get the following error:  `java: cannot find symbol  symbol:   variable NO_WRAP  location: class jodd.util.Base64`.I tried removing the `Base64.NO_WRAP` but then I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jodd.util.Base64`. I am pretty sure I've added the maven dependency for that class. I also tried removing the Base64 completely Like this: `toesGet.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + "token:"+"");` and I still get the `unauthorized` response. I haven't created a variable for the token, entered it as a string directly.